# How to retrieve the Contents of a Json Url using WatiN?

Tags: c#, html, json, watin

How to retrieve the Contents of a Json file using WatiN?

I've tried the below code but the Html property returns  tags and is full of \r\n texts.

```
 public JObject RetrieveAsJson(string url)
        {
            using (var browser = new IE(url))
            {
                return JObject.Parse(browser.Html);
            }
        }
```

The url returns a Json in the browser by default. When I view it in IE, it shows the json data correctly.

Comment: Why do you use WatiN? There are many alternatives like WebClient, Httpclient, HttpWebRequest etc.

Comment: I know because I want to appear as a browser.

Comment: You want to download a json string and also  want to appear as a browser. What does it mean? Your question seems like an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)